# Wie geht es X - Dative or Accusative?

Tags: dative, accusative, salutation

**Wie geht es Ihnen?** - *Ihnen* is a Dative case of *Ihr*. Gut.

**Wie geht es dir?** - *dir* is Dative of *du*. Same thing.

**Wie geht es Herrn Schwarzenberg?** - *den Herrn* is Accusative of *Herr*.

**Wie geht es Ihren Kollegen?** - *Ihren* and *den Kollegen* again are Accusative cases.

So what case should I use in this phrase - Dative or Accusative? And why?

Comment: _Dem Herrn Schwarzenberg_ and _ihren Kollegen_ are dative case, too!

Comment: Please consider consulting a conjugation table next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All your examples use the dative.

The cause of your confusion is that in the third example the dative and the accusative have the same form, so there is no visible difference.

In the forth example, it could be accusative singular or dative plural. As the phrase "wie geht es" requires a dative, "Kollegen" must be plural.

Comment: In the last example, the accusative would be "Ihre Kollegen".

Comment: @RHa Changed, thanks.